# Flutterfire configure error attempting to run a command

Tags: flutter, firebase

I have installed Firebase CLI, but when I run flutterfire configure in my app folder, I get the following error:

```
FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase --version
ERROR: The FlutterFire CLI currently requires the official Firebase CLI to also be installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install_the_firebase_cli for how to install it.
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

First, run the command ***"dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli"***. After running the command ***"dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli"*** you should get a warning message, you just need to add the path to the path variable. Go to the Finder in your Mac. Select "Go->Home" at the top. Inside the home page, use the keyboard shortcut (Command + Shift + .(period)) to show hidden files. Then, look for the file .zshrc. Add the path from the warning message in the zshrc file, it should look like this: export PATH="$PATH":"$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"

Comment: I did add "C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\bin" to environment viriables.

Comment: Can you show me your .zshrc file?

Comment: I'm on windows.

Comment: I think Windows should also has .zshrc file.

Comment: There's only flutterfire.bat in the folder.

Comment: zshrc file located in your home directory. It's a hidden file, so you might not see it in your home directory, but you can view it by running open ~/. zshrc from the terminal.

Comment: Source: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/07/become-command-line-power-user-oh-my-zsh-z/#zsh-settings